# Custom form validation coming from backend

Tags: angular, formbuilder

I'm trying to use a error state retrieved via JSON and use those errors in angular for the form.

I've tried editing the `formBuilder.group` to work with what was received but it's not working.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', Validators.required, Validators.incorrect],
  });

  // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
  this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
}

this.authService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(
  data => {
    if (data.errors) {
      this.f.password.errors.incorrect = data.errors.pass;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    }
  },
  error => {
    this.error = error;
    this.loading = false;
  });
```

```html
<h2>Login</h2>
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
          <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.incorrect">Password is incorrect</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
  <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
</form>
```

```js
  // login call
  login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, { username, password })
        .pipe(map(u_data => {

            return u_data;
        }));
  }
```

I'm getting the correct data from `data.errors`, but I don't know how to show that on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct except that `this.f` and `Validators.incorrect`

first of all remove `Validators.incorrect` because there is no such built-in validators in angular `Validators`

second `this.f` should point to `this.loginForm.controls` in order for this `this.f.password.errors.incorrect` statement to be valid.

just add this getter function to your class and everything should be ok.

```js
  get f() {
    return this.loginForm.controls;
  }
```

here is a working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2pw1ft

Comment: Okay thanks, so I understand it a bit better now, however I get this error. "Cannot set property 'incorrect' of null"

Comment: Ok so you never mentioned adding it to the auth. How would I do that to something I already have? I posted my auth above.

Comment: Ok the auth is just a fake backend i get it.. I'm still getting the error.

Comment: replace `this.f.password.errors.incorrect = data.errors.pass;` with `this.f.password.setErrors({ incorrect: data.errors.pass });` i have updated stackblitz.